# ionic - ion-grid within slides, responsive is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have problem with ionic grid within slides. I have items of product where i put on ion-grid, and ion-grid is within slides, then if i rotate my android device, ion-grid is not responsive, so the image is cut off

```
<ion-col class="hide-xs" size-sm="7" >
    <ion-slides >
       <ion-slide *ngFor="let products of listProduct" >
        <app-ajax [ajax]="ajax"></app-ajax>

        <ion-grid>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6" sizeMd="4" sizeXl="3" *ngFor="let item of products">
              <div class="image-container" *ngIf="item.photo!==''">
                <ion-img *ngIf="item.idproduct !==0" width="100%" height="100%"
                  [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + item.foto64" (click)="presentModal(item)"></ion-img>
              </div>
            
              <div class="fontImage" (click)="presentModal(item)">{{item.nmproduct}}</div>
            </ion-col>    
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </ion-col>
```

if i removed ion-slides, ion-grid responsive properly, so the image is not cut off. how to solve this? thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give this in component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('slides',{static: true}) slides;
 @HostListener('window:resize')
  onResize() {
  setTimeout(() => this.slides.update(), 50);
 }
```